# <ngx-qrcode> QRcode <img> size in Ionic + Angular

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 + Angular and I have this code:

[image: showing screenshot]

What I want to do is resize  element which is rendered by this script:

```
<ngx-qrcode
[qrc-element-type]="'img'"
[(qrc-value)]="address"
class="qrCodeImage"
qrc-errorCorrectionLevel="L"
></ngx-qrcode>
```

to 300 pixels and tried almost all without luck. I guess `#shadow-root` is that issue for me here but is there any way how to style this DOM element without using javascript directly?

UPDATE: SOLVED by updating ngx-qrcode2 to version 9.0.0

Comment: Can you put up your code on stackblitz for viewing? We will be able to help you better.

Comment: This is my part of ionic page: https://pastebin.com/Lw4ndsVR

Comment: the site can't be reached.

Comment: Ok. second try: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b0Vt